# SFML drawing issue in class

Tags: c++, sfml

In this project, I have this `Game` class with the main game loop as one of its functions, a few variables for setting up fonts and stuff as member variables, and a `Window` class; a basic class that wraps around `sf::RenderWindow`.

My issue is that inside the `run` function of the `Game` class, I can clear the window with whatever colour, and display, but cannot draw anything, whether it is a `sf::Text` instance, a `sf::CircleShape`, etc, however, copy and pasting the code into a separate file and compiling that works. `Window::getSFMLWindow()` just returns a reference to the underlying `sf::RenderWindow`, nothing special. I also tried removing my `Window` class and just using `sf::RenderWindow`, and that did nothing, so the problem doesn't lie with the custom window class.

This is my code, unrelated code removed:

## Game.cpp

```
namespace GM {
    Game::Game() {

    }

    int Game::run() {
        sf::Font testFont;
        if(!testFont.loadFromFile(this->fontPath)) {
            std::cerr << "error in loading font" << std::endl; // does not throw error
            return 1;
        }

        sf::Text testText;
            testText.setFont(testFont);
            testText.setString("this is a test string");
            testText.setCharacterSize(30);
            testText.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);


        sf::Event wndEvent;
        while(window.getSFMLWindow().isOpen()) {
            while(window.getSFMLWindow().pollEvent(wndEvent)) {
                switch(wndEvent.type) {
                  case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            window.getSFMLWindow().clear(sf::Color::Black); // does draw

            window.getSFMLWindow().draw(testText); // does not draw

            window.getSFMLWindow().display();
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

## main.cpp

```
int main() {
    GM::Game mainGame;
        mainGame.window.setSize(1200, 675);
        mainGame.window.setTitle("game");
        mainGame.window.setFramerateLimit(60);

        mainGame.fontPath = "./media/font/SourceHanSansJP-Light.otf";


    mainGame.run();
}
```

### Edit:

## Window.hpp:

```
namespace GM {
    class Window {
      public:
        Window(std::string title = "title", int width = 1, int height = 1);

        sf::RenderWindow SFML_Window;
    };
}
```

## Window.cpp:

```
namespace GM {
    Window::Window(std::string title, int width, int height) {
        this->getSFMLWindow().create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), title, sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    }


    sf::RenderWindow& Window::getSFMLWindow() {
        return this->SFML_Window;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `Window` class was very minimal, and I was probably going to improve upon it, but I still cannot see how it would have caused a problem. Maybe because the window was created in a different class than the `Game` one? But the `clear()` and `display()` functions still worked, so I don't know.

Comment: I count five text functions: four that configure `testtext` and one to draw it. What do these functions return?

Comment: Did you try with a different font and different color (text as well as background)?

Comment: @TimRandall they all return void: [sf::Text](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Text.php) & [sf::RenderWindow](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php)

Comment: @nvoigt indeed I have, Cantarell, FreeSans, black on white, white on black, black on blue, grey on black, etc.

Comment: Looks good at first glance, I guess we'll need a [mcve].

Comment: How minimal would you like it to be?

Comment: So, turns out it was the fault of the window class. However, this makes zero sense to me as literally all the class did was hold a `sf::RenderWindow` and have a function that returned a reference to it. Think I'll look into it when I'm less tired. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Would be nice to see your `Window` wrapper class, IMO it has to be related with that somehow

Comment: @alseether alright, added

Comment: Your code worked for me, but some things are missing. First, where is your `getSFMLWindow()` declared? It should be located in `Window.hpp`. Second, as your code is, you can't call `window.close()`, so I assume the proper call is `window.getSFMLWindow().close()`. The only thing I changed aside that, is the font loading, so be sure your font is located where you're looking for it.

Comment: Yeah, I had deleted the file, and I was tired, so I had to recreate it, but with the errors that you mentioned fixed, that was all my window class was. Also, I couldn't draw anything, it wasn't just the text.

Comment: Are you sure your background is being drawn? The default bg color for SFML 
a window is black...

Comment: See my previous comment in response to what different fonts and window colours I have used: "indeed I have, Cantarell, FreeSans, black on white, white on black, black on blue, grey on black, etc. "